# How do I choose which network interface to use from a Docker container?

Tags: docker, networking

I have 2 network interfaces on my Mac - `en0` for regular Ethernet connection, `en6` for a USB LTE modem, the latter has higher priority. I'm running a node.js app in a Docker container, when I make an outbound request from this container, I can see the IP of the modem. For some heavy requests I'd like to be able to use the regular Ethernet connection. Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: This is generally more of a routing question (that is, something that you solve by adding the appropriate routes to your host network configuration)  than a Docker problem. On MacOS, Docker is running in a Linux virtual machine, which may complicate matters. I don't have a Mac on which to check this behavior.

Comment: "when I make an outbound container from this container". What does this mean?

Comment: @BertC, sorry, that was meant to say "request". Basically when I `curl ifconfig.me` from container.